# List executions of a particular Windows process / application

Tags: windows, windows-10, logging

I want to get a usage log for a particular application during the last 30 days.

Does Windows have a log I can access for that?

Comment: If the marked duplicate doesn't cover your question, please explain what you mean by "Usage".  Do you want to know when the application was started?  Or how long it ran for? Or when the user exited? Or how mush disk time it used? How much network traffic it sent? etc. In general though: no, there is no log like this unless you've set up auditing of some kind in advance (see answers on marked duplicate).

Comment: ideally: start of execution; end of execution; normal/abnormal exit; average cpu usage; maximum cpu usage; minimum cpu usage; average memory usage; minimum memory usage; maximum memory usage; A list of files accessed and whether or not they were modified by the process would be perfect.